# Add two decimal digits to a number range regex

Tags: regex, qt, floating-point, qregexp

I've created a Regexp to validate a direction in degrees, between -359 and +359 (with optional sign). This is my regex:

```
const QString xWindDirectionPattern("[+-]{0,1}([0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])");
```

Now, I want to add two decimal numbers, in order to write numbers from -359.99 to +359.99. I've tried something like appending \.[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,3} but It does not work.

I'd like to have optional decimal point so I can have

```
23.3   valid
23.33  valid
23     valid
23.333 not valid
```

I've read some other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers), but I'm not able to modify the example to match a number range, like in my case.
How can I achieve this result?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> I've created a Regexp to validate a direction in degrees, between -359 and +359

No, you *can't*. You *shouldn't*. You are using the wrong tool. Regex cannot do the kinds of validation, which require it to dig into the semantics of the characters.

Regex can only process and match text, but cannot identify what they actually mean. Basically Regex are good for parsing regular language, and bad for almost everything else.

For e.g.:

- A Regex can match 3 digits, but it would be extremely impractical to use it to match 3 digits that fall in range - `[259, 634]`. For that you would need to know the meaning of each individual digits in that number.
- A Regex can match a pattern for date like - `\d\d/\d\d/\d\d`, but it cannot identify which part is `date`, and which part is `month`.
- Similarly, it can find you two numbers `x` and `y`, but it cannot identify, whether `x < y` or not.

The task as above require you to understand the meaning of the text. **Regex can't do that**.

Well, of course you have come up with a regex for sure, but as you can see it is highly un-flexible. A little change in your requirement, will screw both - the regex and you.

You should better use corresponding language features - constructs like `if-else` to make sure you are reading degrees in that range, and not regex.

Comment: I validate numbers after their insertion, but I want to do this because I've a grid cell in which I must put this value and I must to create a validator in order to avoid that the user write wrong data while writing, like inserting letters or putting invalid values. I think that regexp is a good tool for this, but maybe you can suggest something better?

Comment: @Jepessen. Well, some kind of validation you can do by regex, for e.g., testing that a user doesn't any alphabet, where only digits are required, or a field should start with a particular letter, only contain characters from a given set, and should be of a specified length. But some validation like I said, to identify the `range` of a number can't be done. You should use proper language construct for that. BTW, What language are you using?

Comment: Also see [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/113237/66382) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7553722/1679863) post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
[+-]{0,1}((?:[0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)
```

This will allow an a decimal point followed by one or two digits. You'll probably also want to  use start and end anchors (`^` / `$`) to ensure that there are no characters other than this pattern in your string—without this, `23.333` would be allowed because `23.33` matches the above pattern:

```
^[+-]{0,1}((?:[0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

You can test it out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2b-%5D%7B0,1%7D%28%28?%3a%5B0-9%5D%7B1,2%7D%7C%5B12%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C3%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%28?%3a%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1,2%7D%29?%29%24&input=23.3%0A23.33%0A23%0A23.333).

Comment: I can write 359.88, but I can also write, for example, 6334, but in this case no decimal point is allowed.

Comment: @Jepessen I thought the whole idea was to support the range between -359.99 and 359.99. Why would 6334 be allowed?

Comment: Infact I'm saying that I can write also 6334, but I should not be allowed.

Comment: @Jepessen Okay, thanks for clearing that up. You're probably seeing that because it's matching `63` inside `6334`. See my note about using start and end anchors (`^` / `$`). My second pattern would not allow `6334` at all.

Comment: I've just tried, it allows me to write invalid values like 99999. I've checked a bit and If I write a value in my range it works well, but I can also write a value out of range, and in this case decimals are not allowed.

Comment: Are you using the start / end anchors like I suggested? It seems to work fine for me. Test it here: http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2B-%5D%7B0%2C1%7D((%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%7C%5B12%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C3%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D)(%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D)%3F)%24&input=23.3%0A23.33%0A23%0A23.333%0A6334%0A99999

Comment: I don't know what to say... maybe a problem related to QRegExp and QRegExpValidator?

Comment: @Jepessen That's possible. I'm not really familiar with that particular regex engine / validator. According to [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qregexpvalidator.html) the anchors would be assumed. Perhaps it's simply confused and is considering it 'Intermediate'.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to check it in the Qt forum and then return here if I will have any news.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[+-]?([1-9]\d?|[12]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d)(\.\d{1,2})?`.

```
[+-]?          Optional Sign
[1-9]\d?       1 or 2 digit number
[12]\d{2}      100 to 299
3[0-5]\d       300 to 359
(\.\d{1,2})?   Optional decimal point followed by 1 or two digits
```

Comment: It does not seems to work. I can write 1, 12, 2. but not 2.4, 200 ecc

Comment: Putting the regexp into [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=^[%2B-]%3F%28[1-9]\d%3F|[12]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d%29%28\.\d{1%2C2}%29%3F%24), it matches everything I can throw at it.

Comment: I don't know what to say... maybe a problem related to QRegExp and QRegExpValidator?

Comment: This is possible, by the looks of things you're also having issues with p.s.w.g's regular expression too.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to check it in the Qt forum and then return here if I will have any news.