# Regular expression "[ ]" work to weed out white spaces, but why and how?

Tags: c#, regex

To extract the text between the pattern `>>Digit<<`, I have successfully used regex "`(?<=\>>[0-9]+?<<)[ ].+?(?=\>>[0-9]+?<<)`". Regex option is set to single line because the to-be-extracted text may be multiline.

```
>>1<< First Option For Third Variable Reply1 >>1<<

>>2<< Second Option For Third Variable Reply 1 >>2<<

>>3<< Third Option For Third Variable Reply 1 
>>3<<
```

If I remove the `[ ]` portion of the regex "`(?<=\>>[0-9]+?<<).+?(?=\>>[0-9]+?<<)`", matches using the regex will actually extract white spaces (e.g. between `>>1<<` and `>>2<`) which is not my intent. I don't understand why adding [ ] excludes those white spaces.

I understand that square brackets in regex generally signify character classes that are to be included. But here, by inserting square brackets with a space, I manage to exclude the  white spaces (e.g. between `>>1<<` and `>>2<`). So I am trying to understand how it worked in my case.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't ever use regular expressions, no matter how and why. Always write your own algo for parsing text.

Comment: @AlexDepler Thanks for your comment. I have read this and it is very illuminating. I will think of writing ,y own algos to parse text when I have some time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553722/when-should-i-not-use-regular-expressions

Comment: I'd like to put it a lot simpler (than Wiktor's answer) by simply saying - your `[ ]` (which b.t.w. is exactly the same as a space without the brackets) ensures the *tag* (`>>n<<`) is followed by a space, and not any character (`.`) which matches the newline character after a terminating *tag*. You could easily solve it by using a capture group to extract the text and *consume* the *tags* (by **not** having it as a look-arounds). [Illustrated here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BkoTrD/1).

Comment: Thank you for directly answering the question. It sure clears up what i am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that there are whitespaces between `>>2<<` and `>>3<<` and they are matched with `.+?` when the singleline mode is on.

You may try to use a capturing group around the first digit pattern and use a backreference to match the same number on the right:

```
(?<=>>([0-9]+)<<).*?(?=>>\1<<)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3E%3E%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3C%3C%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%3E%3E%5C1%3C%3C%29&i=%3E%3E1%3C%3C%20First%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply1%20%3E%3E1%3C%3C%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E%3E2%3C%3C%20Second%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply%201%20%3E%3E2%3C%3C%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E%3E3%3C%3C%20Third%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply%201%20%0D%0A%3E%3E3%3C%3C&o=s)

**Details**

- `(?<=>>([0-9]+)<<)` - a positive lookbehind making sure there is `>>`, 1+ digits (Group 1), `<<` immediately to the left of the current location
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=>>\1<<)` - a positive lookahead making sure there is `>>`, same number as in Group 1, `<<` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/G3PZnM):

```
var s = ">>1<< First Option For Third Variable Reply1 >>1<<\n\n>>2<< Second Option For Third Variable Reply 1 >>2<<\n\n>>3<< Third Option For Third Variable Reply 1 \n>>3<<";
var rx = @"(?<=>>([0-9]+)<<).*?(?=>>\1<<)";
var results = Regex.Matches(s, rx, RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

Result:

```
 First Option For Third Variable Reply1 
 Second Option For Third Variable Reply 1 
 Third Option For Third Variable Reply 1
```

Another idea is to disallow whitespaces only between the `>>...<<` patterns:

```
(?<=>>[0-9]+<<)(?!\s+>>[0-9]+<<).*?(?=>>[0-9]+<<)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See this [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3E%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%3C%3C%29%28%3F!%5Cs%2B%3E%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%3C%3C%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%3E%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%3C%3C%29&i=%3E%3E1%3C%3C%20First%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply1%20%3E%3E1%3C%3C%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E%3E2%3C%3C%20Second%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply%201%20%3E%3E2%3C%3C%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E%3E3%3C%3C%20Third%20Option%20For%20Third%20Variable%20Reply%201%20%0D%0A%3E%3E3%3C%3C&o=s)