# Is there a library that allows checking if a 24-hour time is valid?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I am trying to check if a given time is valid, using any of python's multiple `datetime` libraries. This given time would be in 24hr format, and examples of valid inputs are `2359`, `0000`, `1330`, while examples of invalid inputs would be `2400`, `2360`, `2500`.

May I ask if there is a better way to check the validity of the input, without parsing through the strings to check individually?

Preferably using python libraries, if possible

If there are no such libraries, may I instead ask how this should be done in regex?

Comment: Try converting it to a `datetime` inside `try/except`.

Comment: regex is simply not the right tool for this.

Comment: @shx2: And exactly why not?

Comment: Relevant: [when should I not use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553722/when-should-i-not-use-regular-expressions)

Comment: You proably could have written the code to do this faster than asking this question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for parsing, with format `%H%M`.  If it fails, it is invalid.

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
    datetime.strptime('2359', '%H%M')
    print('valid')
except ValueError:
    print('invalid')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can attempt to parse it using `time.strptime`:

```
import time

def is_valid_time(value):
    try:
        _ = time.strptime(value, '%H%M')
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a library? You could do it with bare Python code:

```
STRTIME = "2317"

if (0 <= int(STRTIME[:2]) < 24 and 0 <= int(STRTIME[2:]) < 60):
   print("Valid")
```

Comment: what about STRTIME='199'? I would argue you shouldn't try to write parsing code yourself, when a standard one already exists.

Comment: Then you could check the length of the string. It looks simple and readable to me.

Comment: @shx2: on the other hand, one could argue that `strptime` is overkill for this task. Also, applied thousands of times, it would make the code painfully slow, given that it is used only for a simple check like this.

Answer (score 1):

Regex approach need to be added in your date time scenario

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$ (js engine)
```

Logic:

- The first number (hours) is either: a number between 0 and 19 -->
  [0-1]?[0-9] (allowing single digit number) or a number between 20 -
  23 --> 2[0-3]
- the second number (minutes) is always a number between 00 and 59 -->
  [0-5][0-9] (not allowing a single digit)

Answer (score 1):

You might get along with a regular expression:

```
\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/1hYduC/2/).