# Removing extra characters from ansible playbook task

Tags: ansible

Goal of my ansible playbook for Cisco IOS Switch is to check CDP neighbor detail and return the local connecting interface.  Problem is I keep getting extra characters inside my variable so if I try to run task against that interface it doesn't execute.  Here is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Cisco Show CDP Neighbors
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show CDP Interface
      ios_command:
        commands: sh cdp neighbors detail | i Interface
      register: interface

    - name: Extract CDP Interface
      set_fact:
        connecting_interface: "{{ interface.stdout_lines[0] | regex_replace('Interface: ', '') | regex_replace(' Port ID .*', '')}}"

    - name: Print Connecting Interface
      debug:
        var: connecting_interface
```

It returns following:

```
TASK [Print Connecting Interface] **********************************************
ok: [switch-1] => {
    "connecting_interface": "['FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48, "
}
```

I just need it to return `"FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48"`

I tried playing around with `regex_replace` and `replace` but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Can you provide the full output of `register: interface` and or `interface.stdout` or `interface.stdout_lines`?

Comment: @U880D `"Interface: FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet5/0/40"`

Comment: I managed to fix it with this:
`connecting_interface: "{{ interface.stdout_lines[0] | regex_replace('Interface: ', '') | regex_replace(' Port ID .*', '') | regex_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9/]', '')}}"`

Comment: Please add the debug as an [edit] not as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whereby a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook of

```yaml
---
- name: Cisco Show CDP Neighbors
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    result:
      stdout: "Interface: FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet5/0/40"
      stdout_lines:
        - "Interface: FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet5/0/40"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines[0] | regex_replace('Interface: ', '') | regex_replace(' Port ID .*', '') | regex_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9/]', '') }}"
```

will result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48
```

after reading in the [Cisco `cmdrefs` - `show cdp neighbors`](https://www.cisco.com/E-Learning/bulk/public/tac/cim/cib/using_cisco_ios_software/cmdrefs/show_cdp_neighbors.htm) and looking at the example output there, it might can become generalized and simplified in the following way

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.stdout | split(',') | first | from_yaml)['Interface'] }}"
```

- Since there is a single line output only use `stdout` directly ([Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout))
- Split the line on the character / delimiter `,` ([`split()` filter – split a string into a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html))
- Use the left side of the result only ([`first` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names))

At this point one is already with

```yaml
Interface: FiveGigabitEthernet1/0/48
```

and there was [no need for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706275/6771046) removing characters or [regex at all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243/302852).

- Apply [`from_yaml` filter – Convert YAML string into variable structure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/from_yaml_filter.html) and read just the value of the key `Interface`