# Ansible issue in fetching values from host machines and writing to local file, usage of ansible to gather data from nodes

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have this simple playbook that reads a file content => fetches a value
=> append that to a local file,
I want to get a config value for different hosts to be stored in a local file.

```yaml
---
- name: Check file content
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Check if file exists
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: /mydir/myfile.ini
      register: file_stat

    - name: Fetch values and write to a local file
      when: file_stat.stat.exists
      block:
        - name: Read file if it exists
          ansible.builtin.slurp:
            src: /mydir/myfile.ini
          register: file_content

        - name: Set value as a fact
          ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            my_setting: "{{ file_content.content | \
              b64decode | regex_search('^setting_key\\s*?=\\s*?(.*)$', \
              '\\1', multiline=True) | first | trim }}"

        - name: Debug file content
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: '{{ my_setting }}'

        - name: Write fetch value to a file
          become: false
          ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
            path: my_settings.txt
            line: '{{ inventory_hostname }} - {{ my_setting }}'
            create: true
            mode: '644'
            insertafter: 'EOF'
          delegate_to: localhost
          # when: >
          #   my_setting is defined and
          #   my_setting != "MY_SETT_VALUE"
          # with_items: '{{ my_setting }}'
```

However, this playbook behaves inconsistently. If I run it against two hosts, sometimes there will be two lines in the output file `my_settings.txt`, one for each host, as expected.
But sometimes there will be only one line or one host information(most of the time), and the other host’s value is missing.

Is this due to some race condition? How can I fix this issue?

The debug lines always show the correct values for different hosts, so the problem is not with reading or fetching the value.

Note: the source file is located in remote node,

*Edit: I wrote this quick play to gather the values of a settings file from different nodes (ansible come to my mind as the need arise). However, as the answer pointed out, there are several issues with the playbook and I also realized that.*

*There is a chance of file lock failure and data overriding in this approach. So, my question is: Is Ansible intended to be used like this, i.e. to collect data from different nodes and store it in a local file or a database? If yes, what is the best way to do that?*

*For example, if I need to prepare a report comparing my nodes, how can I check the data from different nodes and store it in a central node?*

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what is the content of „the file“? Are you trying to gather configuration information from remote nodes and write it into a kind of database, like gathering facts? If so, what kind of configuration, service is the INI file for?

Comment: It is a custom settings file, `key = value` format, for an application, need to check if all nodes contain exact same value, that is my case,
- yes the file i am trying to read is on remote nodes,
the file/content can be anything, the issue is with writing them to a local file.
question updated

Answer (score 1):

Just some notes ahead

- [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials - Think declaratively](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials)

  > *Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.*
- [Idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency)

  > *An operation is idempotent if the result of performing it once is exactly the same as the result of performing it repeatedly without any intervening actions.*
- For an INI file, see [When should I not use regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706275/6771046) and [When you should not use regular expressions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243/302852)
- There is no need to [`slurp`s a file from Remote Nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) to the Control Node or to do the processing centralized at all

Based on that your current approach is neither simple nor recommended.

---

> ***I need to check if all nodes contain exact same value in an INI file***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Make sure that custom settings file is in Desired State
    ini_file:
      path: "./custom.setting"
      section: Nodes
      option: SameValue
      value: "True"
      create: true
    diff: true
    register: result
```

will result into an required file **`custom.setting`**

```ini
[Nodes]
SameValue = True
```

and an output of

```yaml
TASK [Make sure that custom settings file is in Desired State] ******
--- before: ./custom.setting (content)
+++ after: ./custom.setting (content)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@

 [Nodes]
-SameValue = False
+SameValue = True
```

For auditing and checks one can use

```yaml
  - name: Audit and report custom settings file
    ini_file:
      path: "./custom.setting"
      section: Nodes
      option: SameValue
      value: "True"
    check_mode: true
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result.changed
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Audit and report custom settings file] ******
ok: [test.example.com]

TASK [debug] **************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result.changed: false
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html)
- [Using `check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode)
- [using `diff` mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-diff-mode)

Also already available out-of-box is

- [Logging Ansible output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html)

as well maintaining the Configuration State as a kind of

- [Custom fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is exactly why I asked this question here. 
So, Is it a good practice to use Ansible to gather data from different nodes? If yes, what is the best way to do that?
I think the issue I am facing is due to file lock. Yes I can use the ini_parser module to directly update the file contents, and using regex when a parser exists is wrong. I wrote a quick play just to grab some data, but when I saw it behave like this, I posted a question. I am also editing my question to that context.

Comment: "_So, Is it a good practice to use Ansible to gather data from different nodes?_", yes, in the way I've showed. "_I can use the `ini_file` module to directly update the file contents_", not only, also to audit, check and diff in the way I've showed. "_and using regex when a parser exists is wrong._", in your case there is still no need for regex at all.

Comment: Yes I got that, in case I if my need is to grab data from different nodes and store it in a central database/file, like for e.g., I have 10 database nodes, I need to run a select query on each node and then store the result to a local database In order to prepare a report is it an intended way to use ansible for.

Comment: Hello, asking a follow up,If I need to update mysql database configuration in remote nodes, I can use `community.mysql.mysql_variables` but that just not persists a server restart, to persist that settings to `mysql**.cnf`, which module to use `ini_file` ?? `cnf` and `ini` are somewhat different I think. In that cases what is the best method to choose to go with `lineinfile`..
I cannot use a fixed template end state as some other configurations are different on the nodes, just needs the end state as a single config such as `log_error_verbosity=2` (eg) to be present in all nodes.

Comment: @AkshayChandran, for such new question, request and requirement just file a new question here on SO.

Comment: Okay, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77845072/12167598 :+1:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77845193/12167598, thanks in advance